# How to implement drawerlayout with custom action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

If i use default actionbar i can set home button to open and close drawerlayout with this code.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

And it's work well.

But i dont't want default actionbar i want actionbar with customlayout.

When i use custom actionbar i don't know how to implement home button for open and close drawerlayout.

How to implement drawerlayout with custom action bar?

PS. I use custom actionbar because i want set title text to align center of actionbar, set text and text size to it's.

**EDIT**

thank you every body i can solve it's by use this.

```
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
```

it's work well but the home button image change from app logo to app icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Action bar like this ..

// gets actionBar reference ..

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

// This sets custom layout to action bar

```
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_provider);
```

// this is how... .... you get id of layout defined

```
iv_d = (ImageView) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.action_menu);
```

Now just open you drawer on click of this icon using OnClick()

That's it .. you are good to go.